# Bunny left outside now experiencing problems

Tags: behavior, health, rabbits

My mom left my bunny (10 weeks old) outside for about 4 hours, with the temperature being around 86 °F (30 °C). Then, when I went for it, its mouth was wet and its two front paws I have no idea how it got wet.

Also, when I went to pick it up it started to kick and jump, mind you it has never done this before, but I brought him in and now he is acting strange and laying weird (as illustrated by attached pictures).

Also, when he walks or hops he doesn't move positions and I have no idea what to do, does anyone know? Should I take him to the vet or what?

Please help, I'm worried.

[image]

Comment: Nevermind he passed away  my poor baby 

Comment: Take him to the vet urgently! he may be suffering from heat stroke, could have been bitten by a snake, hit by a car or any number of things. I just read your answer. I'm so sorry for your loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you should probably take it to a vet it looks like an emergency. Your bunny may be about to die from dehydration or some kind of poisen or infection.Go now!

Comment: He didnt make it  my baby passed away .. i cant stop crying im so hurt .

Comment: I'm so sorry to hear, let it rest in peace.

Answer (score 3):

In any cases like this ***EMERGENCY VETERINARY CARE*** is required. No matter what time of day or night. A vet can offer intravenous fluids and appropriate medications, that cannot be provided at home.

Any pet should not be exposed to extremes of climate, more so babies. They are more vulnerable and need more protection than adults. A 10 week old bunny has not long been weaned and vulnerable. Excessive heat can kill them and they should [not be exposed to temperature above 65 - 75 degrees](http://rabbit.org/faq-orphaned-baby-bunnies/) Fahrenheit(18 - 24 degrees Celsius)

In 86 degrees Fahrenheit heat (30 degrees Celsius), the baby bunny would need to be indoors in a cooler environment and have access to fresh water.

Comment: Definitely heat stroke like Yvette said. You said you don't know how it's mouth & feet and were wet: 2 things1- heat exhaustion (Before heatstroke) causes nausea & drooling & lands on feet 2- heat stroke isn't a mild term, it's an actual stroke... Parts of his body may no longer be able to communicate properly w/the brain, ie leg placement, swallowing  saliva, urinating, sounding like what you've described. I try to stay very positive on this site but the person who left this bunny outside caused this baby hours of pain & suffering, & if it makes it thru, a lifetime of suffering. So so sorry.

Comment: Oh so sorry, didn't read that he infact passed. I'm sorry for your lost.... Poor little booger